# How can I send a batch variable to a powershell command

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I don't know how to fix it...

I'm trying to move random files from one folder to another but I want so I can determine the folders inside the batch file but when I run the batch file it doesn't work and if I change the `%var%` manual from editing the batch file it's working.

I'm sorry if this is a simple question but I'm kinda new to batch and still learning.

```
@echo off

set /p var1=Enter first dir:
set /p var2=Enter second dir:

::Var (Folder Directory)

echo %var1%
echo %var2%

powershell -Command "& {%var1% | Get-Random -Count 5 | Copy-Item -Destination %var2%}"

pause
```

Comment: Your use example works, here is a simplified example that batch variables can be expanded when they are required in PowerShell command line: `set var1=B && PowerShell -c "& echo %var1%"`. Why shouldn't that work??

Comment: Is there any reason not to do the whole thing in PowerShell? `$source = Read-Host 'source'; $dest = Read-Host 'destination'; Get-ChildItem -Path $source | Get-Random -Count 5 | Copy-Item -Destination $dest`. Also you mention moving, but use `Copy-Item` instead of `Move-Item`, is that intentional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **`$env:var`** in PowerShell

```
@echo off & cd /d "%~dp0"

set /p "var1=Enter first dir: "
set /p "var2=Enter second dir: "

echo %var1% & echo %var2%

powershell -nop -c "ls $env:var1 | Get-Random -Count 5 | Copy-Item -Destination $env:var2"

pause
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason access those variables from within PowerShell itself, as they are parsed/expanded by cmd.exe before being passed to it.

The biggest issues with your shown method, is that you should use `Get-ChildItem`, *(`gci`, `dir`, `ls`)*, to list the items in `%var1%`, and enclose your variables within single quotes, or escaped doublequotes, to ensure they are understood to be valid strings.

```
%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile "Get-ChildItem \"%var1%\" -File -Force | Get-Random -Count 5 | Copy-Item -Destination \"%var2%\""
```